# Stripe : Authorizing Cards for a longer period

Tags: authorization, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

We are trying to implement a Delayed Payment System where the application owner as well as sellers gets paid after the service is provided to the customer. At the same time we would also like to authorize customers card in advance. We understand that authorization process allows you to authorize the card only for 7 days. But our requirement needs the card to be authorized for a longer period. What other alternative does stripe have to satisfy our requirement.

Comment: This is not something Stripe supports. You should talk to their support team though as it's not really a coding question: https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: This question is more for Stripe support